# QTP: different lenghts of two variables with same values

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I faced with unexpected difficulty while trying to compare two variables:

First variables comes from XML:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(array, 2)
    If Bk  = array(0, i) Then
       Book= cstr(array(1, i))
      Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Imagine `Book = "LONDON"`

Second variables (SQLBook) comes from SQL select and if to use WATCH in QTP  var BOOK and SQLBOOK are equal visually, but if we compare them via `LEN()`: BOOK has 8 length (`len(Book)`) and SQLBook has 9 lenght.

Could you please advise what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a space or some invisible character in the SQLBook. To find out the difference between the two variables do the following:

1) First remove the similar characters:

```
Dim diff AS String = Replace(SQLBook, BOOK, "")
```

2) Then check the ASCII code of the character left in diff:

```
Debug.Print Asc(diff)
```

**EDIT** As per your comment, the difference is a **Carriage Return** character which is used to make a new line. To get rid of it, use:

```
Replace(SQLBook, vbCr, "")
```

Comment: I tried to do  what you kindly suggested me and asc() returned 13: diff = Replace(SQLBook, Book, "")
Msgbox asc(diff)

Comment: @AlexPes  Yes, as I expected, that's a **Carriage Return** character which is used to make a new line. You can remove it using the `Trim()` function. See my updated answer.

Comment: I did  'SQLBook = "select  book  from testtable  where id = "& SYSTEMID &" " Rec.open SQLBook, objConn 
Set rec=objConn.Execute(SQLBook)
TradeBook=rec.GetString
Trim(TradeBook) ' and it did not help me unfortunately

Comment: OK, try `Replace()` instead of `Trim()`, I updated my answer.